# Resize grip in GTK2

Tags: c, gtk, gtk2

I'm writing a GTK2 application. I want to add resize grip in the bottom right corner of the window, [but the API does not provide any functions to do so](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkWindow.html) (`gtk_window_set_has_resize_grip()` is limited to GTK3). However, I can see many programs written using GTK2 with resize grips (older versions of Pluma, Caja, and Geany among others). I have tried looking at Pluma's source code and globally searching for keywords like "grip," "resize_grip" and "resize", but I got no results in either case. I'd appreciate an answer that goes into detail about how to implement resize grip in GTK2.

Comment: My window had a grip and I didn't have to do anything.

Comment: @oldtechaa Well, my doesn't, but I can see other applications on my system that have it, so I figured out there must be something they are doing that I'm not. I'm running Ubuntu MATE 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

```
static gboolean resize_expose(GtkWidget *area, GdkEventExpose *ev, GdkWindowEdge edge) {
  gint size = MIN(area->allocation.width, area->allocation.height);

  gtk_paint_resize_grip(area->style, area->window,
      gtk_widget_get_state(area),
      &ev->area, area, "grip", edge,
      area->allocation.width - size, area->allocation.height - size,
      size, size);

  return TRUE;
}

static gboolean resize_button(GtkWidget *area, GdkEventButton *ev, GdkWindowEdge edge) {
  if (ev->type != GDK_BUTTON_PRESS)
    return TRUE;

  switch (ev->button) {
  case 1:
    gtk_window_begin_resize_drag(GTK_WINDOW(gtk_widget_get_toplevel(area)), edge,
        ev->button, ev->x_root, ev->y_root, ev->time);
    break;
  case 2:
    gtk_window_begin_move_drag(GTK_WINDOW(gtk_widget_get_toplevel(area)),
        ev->button, ev->x_root, ev->y_root, ev->time);
    break;
  }

  return TRUE;
}

void create_grip(GtkWidget *parent_or_window) {
  GtkWidget *area = gtk_drawing_area_new();
  gtk_widget_set_size_request(area, 18, 18);
  gtk_widget_add_events(area, GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK);
  gtk_box_pack_end(GTK_BOX(parent_or_window), area, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
  g_signal_connect(area, "expose_event", G_CALLBACK(grip_expose),
      GINT_TO_POINTER(GDK_WINDOW_EDGE_SOUTH_EAST));
  g_signal_connect(area, "button_press_event", G_CALLBACK(grip_button),
      GINT_TO_POINTER(GDK_WINDOW_EDGE_SOUTH_EAST));
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer too so everyone can learn from your answer.